# how get unique rows using join from one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am using codeigniter 2 in my project and I have a problem that I hope that you'll help me in solving it.

I have two mysql tables,"**authors**" and "**articles**" where relation is as "one author to many articles". I need to get authors "from '**authors**'" that have already active articles in "**articles**".

**note** that in articles table, I have column called "status_id" that set to 1 if the article is active or 0 if suspended. and I have in "**authors**" table a record called "authors_categories_id".

I tried to do it with this code

```
$this->db->select('authors.name,authors.about,authors.author_thumbnail,authors.authors_categories_id,authors.user_id,authors.status_id,authors.id AS auth_id')
                  ->from('authors')
                  ->join('articles', 'authors.id = articles.author_id')
                  ->where('authors.authors_categories_id',$AuthCategory)
                  ->where('articles.status_id', 1)
                  ->order_by("auth_id", "desc")
                  ->limit($limit, $start);
            $Res = $this->db->get();
            $data['Authors'] = array();
            foreach($Res->result() as $R)
            {
                $data['Authors'][] = $R;
            }
            print_r($data['Authors']);
```

My problem that the code results me duplicated authors. ***for example***, if an author have 5 articles in 'articles' table, **the result will be 5 records for the same author while i need to view each author just once not more**.

I need the code to generate records according to count of authors not articles.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `DISTINCT` in your query.

```
select('authors.name,authors.about,authors.author_thumbnail,authors.authors_categories_id,authors.user_id,authors.status_id,authors.id AS auth_id')
              ->from('authors')
              ->join('articles', 'authors.id = articles.author_id')
              ->where('authors.authors_categories_id',$AuthCategory)
              ->where('articles.status_id', 1)
              ->group_by('authors.name');
              ->order_by("auth_id", "desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('authors.name,authors.about,authors.author_thumbnail,authors.authors_categories_id,authors.user_id,authors.status_id,authors.id AS auth_id')
                  ->from('authors')
                  ->join('articles', 'authors.id = articles.author_id')
                  ->where('authors.authors_categories_id',$AuthCategory)
                  ->where('articles.status_id', 1)
                  ->group_by('authors.id')
                  ->order_by("auth_id", "desc")
                  ->limit($limit, $start);
            $Res = $this->db->get();
            $data['Authors'] = array();
            foreach($Res->result() as $R)
            {
                $data['Authors'][] = $R;
            }
            print_r($data['Authors']);
```

Note the `->group_by('authors.id')` in the code now. This should group all of the same authors together.